# How to connect to wifi using just the terminal?

Tags: wireless

i need to learn to do it just using the commands in the terminal. any help would really help thanks

Comment: Is this a desktop or a server? If it is a desktop, then NetworkManager will probably disallow other methods to connect.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which version? Do you want to reload an existing connection, or are you attempting the initial setup? What sort of authentication does the wifi use?

Comment: @singrium Those old answers assume that the encryption is WEP. That's not likely the case today.

Comment: @chili555, Thank you, I'll delete my comments then.

Comment: @chili555 it is a desktop kubuntu 19.04
i want to connect to a new wireless network

Answer (score 8):

I suggest that you do the following steps:

```
nmcli device wifi rescan
nmcli device wifi list
nmcli device wifi connect my_lil_router password 1234567890
```

Of course, substitute your exact details here.

Comment: Hello! Thank you this works perfect!

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: **+1** Doctor Chili555 is requested in the [operating rtoom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164789/no-connection-with-broadcom-bcm4311-802-11b-g-wlan-wireless-card).  [Paging Doctor Chili555](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MWXNh.png)...