# no connection with Broadcom BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN wireless card

Tags: networking, drivers, lubuntu, lenovo, broadcom

I've had no wireless connection since I installed Lubuntu 18.04.3 recently (on a Lenovo 3000 N-100 notebook with a `BCM4311 802.11 b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)` hardware).

I've read several Ask Ubuntu questions. For example, [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)  and followed the section titled **Installing The Package (Online)**, but there is still no wireless connection even after doing a `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source` and after installing the correct driver with `sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer` and then rebooting.

I am told that all is OK with the driver, as the response to `sudo lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` command is

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:0465]
 Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
 Kernel modules: ssb 

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
```

I was indeed connected to the internet while installing firmware-b43-installer.

Command 'sudo modprobe b43' does not work.

The output of 'dmesg | tail' is
[   15.327311]  excluding 0x60000000-0x60ffffff
[   15.327343] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: IO port probe 0xa00-0xaff:
[   15.331876]  clean
[   16.005244] intel_powerclamp: No package C-state available
[   16.044635] intel_powerclamp: No package C-state available
[   23.255005] 8139too 0000:05:01.0 enp5s1: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xC1E1
[   23.431486] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
[  727.137035] perf: interrupt took too long (2502 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750
[ 1173.265545] perf: interrupt took too long (3136 > 3127), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63750
[ 2237.034712] perf: interrupt took too long (3929 > 3920), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50750

*As I'm rather new to Ubuntu, please be clear and provide exact instructions to follow...*

**POSTSCRIPT TO MY QUESTION**

THE WIFI CONNECTION IS NOW WORKING !!!!!!
Thanks to combined effort from **@Pilot6**, **@Fabby**, and **@chili555**

After @chili555 advised me as follows:
*"Your device requires the driver b43 and firmware and NOT bcmwl-kernel-source
Check if the firmware is present and loading:
sudo modprobe b43 && dmesg | grep b43

If there are no complaints about firmware, then the hardware switch must be set to airplane mode disabling the wireless; check:
rfkill list all
If you see Hard block:yes then you need to find the switch and switch it."*

I toggled the wifi hardware switch again (for about the 10th time).
Then I ran the commands that chili555 suggested.

Then I noticed that THE WIFI CONNECTION IS NOW WORKING.

Here are the results of the commands that chili555 suggested.

The output from 'sudo modprobe b43 && dmesg | grep b43' is

'[ 4.275681] b43-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: Sonics Silicon Backplane found on PCI device 0000:03:00.0
[ 14.725274] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4311 WLAN found (core revision 10)
[ 14.767477] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 4, Type 2 (G), Revision 8
[ 14.767488] b43-phy0: Found Radio: Manuf 0x17F, ID 0x2050, Revision 2, Version 0
[ 23.431486] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
[10967.655484] b43-phy0: Radio hardware status changed to DISABLED
[10972.807505] b43-phy0: Radio hardware status changed to ENABLED
[10972.983536] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)'

The output from 'rfkill list all' is 
'0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no'

Comment: It is unclear what device you have. What is product ID? Probably you installed a wrong driver.

Comment: Read https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/167850 carefully and if you have problems, [edit] your question and add more details.

Comment: Pilot6. When you say it isn't clear what product, which product,and how  do I identify it?

Comment: I gave you a link. Did you click and read it? It says how to identify and what to do next.

Comment: Most likely you need to run `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source` because it's a wrong driver.

Comment: Pilot6. The link you gave me is exactly the one I believe I implemented through the section therein titled Installing The Package (Online). In that process I found that the wireless card is:  BCM4311 802.11 b/g WLAN [14e4 4311] (rev 01)

Comment: So you need to purge `bcmwl-kernel-source` and install `firmware-b43-installer`. But you installed a wrong one. You never mentioned which "package" did you install. Ther is no single The Package.

Comment: Pilot6. before asking this AskUbuntu question, I had purged 'bcmwl-kernel-source' and I had installed 'firmware-b43-installer'. I will repeat those steps if knowing that, you recommend that I repeat them.

Comment: According to your screenshot `bcmwl-kernel-source` is installed. That is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97276/discussion-between-hotspur-and-pilot6).

Comment: My chat request with Pilot6 didn't get a response to now,  after 25 minutes.. Therefore I have edited my question to show that I followed the suggestions made by Pilot6, and  the problem persists.

Comment: Please post output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` to your question.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. My notebook's (US) keyboard appears not to have the vertical line needed in the first command. I've seen that character on anexternal keyboard, but don't have one of those now.

Comment: Response to 'sudo lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list' is 
'03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:0465]
 Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
 Kernel modules: ssb
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no'

Comment: All is OK with the driver. Please ass information to your question. Comments may be removed. Please also add output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: BTW, were you conected to internet when installung `firmware-b43-installer`? Did the package really installed?

Comment: Run `sudo modprobe b43`. If wifi doesn't work, post output of `dmesg | tail` TO YOUR QUESTION NOT TO COMMENTS.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and just leave the question bit in there.  Answers are posted on the duplicate...  **0:-)**