# Network Manager couldn't reserve IP configuration

Tags: command-line, networking, apt, wireless, network-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I connected to Ethernet to install Network Manager using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

All went perfectly with no errors. I then start Network Manager with

```
service network-manager start
```

Then finally I go to connect to my Wifi with the following command

```
nmcli d wifi connect <Wifi Name> Password <Password>
```

When I do this I get the following error:

```
Error: Connection activation failed: (5) IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.).
```

I found another thread suggesting to use the command `journalctl -f`

to see the logs on the error. Nothing appears strange here, nowhere does it say anything is missing or broken.

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` returns

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:5390]
        Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [105b:e088]
        Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
        Kernel modules: rt2800pci
```

`nmcli dev status` returns

```
(Device)wlp2s0 (Type)wifi (State)disconnected (Connection)--
```

Ethernet and Loopback devices are unmanaged

What is going on here? Does anybody know how I can fix this, or at least how I can connect to my Wifi at all?

Comment: @kashish I cannot follow those steps because I do not have a desktop interface on my system

Comment: Did you: `sudo apt update` and then: `sudo apt install wireless-tools wpasupplicant` and finally, the steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164074/how-to-connect-to-wifi-using-just-the-terminal/1164095#1164095