# Deleted terminal and nothing is working

Tags: dual-boot, apt, python, gnome-terminal, python3

I was randomly looking at how to tweet from terminal and downloaded https://github.com/orakaro/rainbowstream in their readme I followed quick install. Then while removing it I accidentally ran `sudo apt-get remove python-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev`
Soon did I realise what I had done it was too late. The terminal had been deleted I panicked and I reastarted the laptop and it had windows+ubuntu on dual boot .. now in the bootloader menu only ubuntu and ubuntu advance options is showing, when I try to open ubuntu it recursively keeps asking me my username and password. And I can't even log into windows anymore. What can I do to get out of this mess? I guess I'm screwed

Comment: Lesson learned: Apt warns you what it is about to remove. Read the list. Understand the list. If the list is too long, or you don;t understand, then DON'T agree to the removal.

Comment: *"What can I do"* - You can reinstall the OS

Answer (score 1):

1. At the graphical login screen, use CTRL+ALT+F3 to switch to a tty (text only) terminal.
2. Login to the tty using your normal username/password
3. Test your network connectivity: `ping -c4 8.8.8.8`.

   - You should get a result `4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss`. If not, see [How to connect to wifi using just the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164074/how-to-connect-to-wifi-using-just-the-terminal)
4. Restore your Desktop with `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`
5. When the install completes, reboot: `sudo reboot now`

Comment: thanks, i got the same suggestion from reddit to do a ctrl alt f3 but it kept asking me login details RECURSIVELY for some reason and i ended up wiping the harddisk clean and doing a new install