# I can't connect to WiFi via ubuntu 18.04 terminal

Tags: command-line, networking, network-manager, iwlwifi

```
root@secure-OS:~# wpa_passphrase " Galaxy Xcover 4E575" 777777 | sudo tee /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
tee: /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf: Read-only file system
network={
         ssid="Galaxy Xcover 4E574"
         #psk="777777"
         psk=ffc9bfc2f55cb27107f65d9a44f734bc9ce0a26f4b2f1ad98bf5bc8f30f38757
}
root@Secure-OS:~# sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf-i wlp2s0
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant 
Failed to read or parse configuration '/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: `nmtui` will do this for you. It is not OpenWRT.

Comment: Or `nmcli` : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164074/how-to-connect-to-wifi-using-just-the-terminal/1164095#1164095