# Force network interface with nmcli?

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, nmcli

I want to connect to a specific BSSID via nmcli.
I am using the command:

```
nmcli d wifi connect xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:01
```

While it kinda works, it wants to force connection via wlan0 network interface.
Is there any way I can specify the network interface to wlan1 with nmcli? Or with any other command for that matter.
Thanks in advance forum!

Comment: Are you using a supported Ubuntu release? Which? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: I am not sure I know which versions are supported. Sorry I am not experienced enough but I am running Ubuntu 20.04.4

Comment: Is one 2.4 GHz and the other 5 GHz?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164074/how-to-connect-to-wifi-using-just-the-terminal/1164095#1164095  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Both are 2,4ghz and 5ghz compatible.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit] Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting