# How to just check Wifi Access Point connectivity by script Linux Ubuntu Server

Tags: networking, wireless, bash, scripts

I'm writing bash script that configure network access for my Linux devices.

The script has to be used by not Linux skilled people that has no administrative rights on the device.
I wrote the ethernet interfaces configuration part and it's ok. Now I need write *Wifi* configuration part.

The end of the game is to write configuration inside a `netplan configuration yaml file`.
Here the expected workflow of the script:

1. manage interactive menu system retrieving Hi-level Wifi parameter (SSID, password, authentication mode, dhcp or manual configuration...)
2. Check the Connectivity to the selected Access point
3. Save data to netplan configuration yaml file
4. Apply changes

Point `1, 3 and 4` are ok... also retrieving the list of the available access point is ok.

What I cannot achieve is the point `2` (*Check the Connectivity to the selected Access point*). I would like to have an use experience like the next

```
WIFI configuration parameters:
    SSID: My Network
    PSK:  password
Actions:
    - e: Edit
    - t: Test connectivity
    - s: Save
    - q: Quit
Select Action: t
....wait while testing connectivity
Test result: OK
Press a key to continue...
```

I tried with `iwconfig` but it's not working with WPA so it does not apply to the most cases.

I tried `wpa_supplicant` and I can do the test but not in the way I'm thinking... It's a foreground test that can be stopped only with `ctrl-C` and is hard to read for dummies (my final user taget).

I would like to

1. launch the Wifi connection in background
2. test in background if the connection to Access Point is ok or not
3. close the Wifi connection in back ground (the final goal is to configure netplan)
4. Return an OK/Fail response to calling script

Of course it is possible to run `wpa_supplicant` connection in `bg` but: how to check connectivity and stop it always in `bg`?

Any suggestion?

Thanks
Sandro

Comment: "tried with iwconfig but it's not working with WPA " It certainly does work with WPA/WPA2 and even WPA3. Please clarify. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: when I try something like `sudo iwconfig wlp4s0 essid MYWIFI key s:ABCDE12345` i get the next response:
`Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) : SET failed on device wlp4s0 ; Invalid argument.` Googling it looks like issue with iwconfig and wpa network

Comment: Your question says you want to just check connectivity. Your comment here suggests that you want to use `iwconfig` to initially connect. Please clarify.

Comment: I was thinking to temporary setup the connection in order to see if credentials are correct and connection can be done. Is there a better way to test connectivity?

Comment: If you want to change networks on a server, very unusual, I suggest Network Manager and specifically `nmcli`. Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164074/how-to-connect-to-wifi-using-just-the-terminal/1164095#1164095

Comment: You can simply test connectivity with `iwconfig | grep ESSID` Either the answer is the SSID to which you are connected, or, if not connected, *off/any*.

Comment: @chili555 Thanks for your suggestion, but this is not what I'm asking. I know how to get ESSID list and how to test if the network is connected... I'm asking how to connect, make a test and disconnect in background so that my dummy user can only wait a response: _yes you configured right network name and password_ or _No, you cannot connect with name and password... change something and retry_  
Do you think that Network Manager can help with this?

Comment: I'm confused. Your question was: "How to just check Wifi Access Point connectivity" but your comment here says: "I know how to get ESSID list and how to test if the network is connected." Sorry but I haven't any other suggestions.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear.
I have not to perform this for myself. I need a script that will be run on devices on industrial plants where nobody know anything about Linux. So I need to ask people ESSID, PASSWORD and then say to them _Ok device can connect_,  or _Device cannot connect_... then script will ask them if they want to save and apply or quit.
What I miss is: How to automate this in a background process that only returns to main script _Connection OK/KO_?

Comment: Sorry, I know very little about writing scripts. nmcli clearly shows available networks and says either *Error: Connection activation failed* or else *Device 'wlp3s0' successfully activated* where wlp3s0 is the relevant interface.